# Strange arithmetic error with vectors

Tags: c#

I am using DirectX to draw on screen.

I want to make the image about whilst keeping the dimensions, so I am assigning some arithmetic to the vertexes:

```
float boxPosFactorX = (869-3)+(100/100 * (1063 - 869));
float boxPosFactorY = (940-3)+(100/100 * (1038 - 940));



vertexes[0].Position = new Vector4((50 * boxScale) + boxPosFactorX, (50 * boxScale) +     boxPosFactorY, 0, 1.0f);

// other vertexes with same structure just different constants (e.g. 50 above is the constant values of that vertex.
```

Now here is the really weird part, the code above works as expected, but as soon as change the ratio "100/100" to anything below "99/100" or less, it behaves as if the code were:

```
float boxPosFactorX = (869-3)
float boxPosFactorY = (940-3)
```

Comment: Another day, another person not understanding floating point :*(

Comment: Lack of knowledge != lack of understanding ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`99/100` is `0` (and `101/100` is exactly `1`). That is integer arithmetic. If you want floating point arithmetic, use `99F/100`.

Comment: Thank you, I cant tell anyone how long I have debugged this :(

Comment: @user1166981 probably best not to ;p